# Solace error 403: Message VPN Not Allowed

Tags: java, jms, solace

I am trying to connect to solace queue using solace APIs. After Successful connection, I am getting error : Error Code 403 Message VPN Not Allowed.

I have written code to connect WAR file to Solace queue. I have provided all the details and able to connect to queue with out failure (Logger is displaying success messages). But post deployment, it starts throwing  error message : Error Code 403 Message VPN Not Allowed.

The java doc describes "The Message VPN does not contain a username that matches the one provided by the REST HTTP client", but I feel this could not be issue as I am able to connect to sollace at first instance and then JBoss reverts build and undeploys it because of above error.

I am unable to find/debug root cause of this issue as I am unable to find call hierarchy of failed code.

Answer (score 2):

`Message VPN Not Allowed` is caused by attempting to connect to a Message VPN that does not exist.

Please verify whether the Message VPN that is specified by your application/configuration files exists on the Solace message broker.

> I have provided all the details and able to connect to queue with out
>   failure (Logger is displaying success messages). But post deployment,
>   it starts throwing error message : Error Code 403 Message VPN Not
>   Allowed.

From your description, it appears that your testing/debugging/development environment is not the same after deploying.